# If specific div is in viewport fade in audio, if div is out of viewport fade out

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a one page scrolling website, and what I would like to do is fade in and out ambient sounds per section. I have found a few libs that fade sound in and out on pixels but being that this site scales I cant get them to trigger properly.

Basically it would be for each section:

```
<div class="section_content" id="1"> /// this is the section that would need to trigger audio file 1
  <div class="main_image">
  </div>
  <div class="main_content">
  Text content and information here 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section_content" id="2"> /// this is the section that would need to trigger audio file 2
  <div class="main_image">
  </div>
  <div class="main_content">
  Text content and information here 
  </div>
</div>
```

https://github.com/kamblack/AudioFade/blob/master/README.md

This was the library I tied but since its based off of pixels it wont quite work.

Comment: what's scaling the divs? just css?

Comment: Just css using flexbox and in some cases some images are set to 100vh.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport?rq=1 can you use this related question to check if a particular element is currently visible and do the fading in/out based on that?

Comment: @jamie Are you only allowing scrolling from one div to another? As in, I couldn't see half of one and half of another?

Comment: @zfrisch  all the content takes up at least the full view port or longer. I would say most  sections are about 1.5 to 3 full scrolls on a desktop monitor and a bit more on mobile.

Comment: @jamie If that's the case, are there situations where 2 different audios would be playing simultaneously?

Comment: @zfrisch Nope. Each section has a main div then children div inside with their specific layouts. I was planning on trying to track the overall main divs per each section.

Comment: @jamie Okay, I think I understand. I'll see if I can help. Could you post this information in the main question (instead of the comments), and if you have it, possibly a screen of what the page looks like.

Comment: @zfrisch Done with the basic structure of the site!

Comment: @jamie great! Last thing. How are you embedding audio? Just a library, or did you write your own code?

Comment: @zfrisch the two ways I tried it was just with simple audio tags and js. I found a few solutions here and other places that I tried to modify using the above JS library and i tried to modify code that works for video players in the viewport.